# Normalizing various form input values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following repetitive code:

```
// (3) Change to whether user has an acceptable rate or not
$('.rate-ok').on("change", function(event) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var field = "rate_ok";
    var value = $(this).is(':checked');
    console.log(id, field, value)
    $.post('/update_data/', {'id': id, 'field': field, 'value': value}, function (response) {
        location.reload();
    })
});

// (4) Change on status
$('.status').on("change", function(event) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var field = "status";
    var value = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    console.log(id, field, value)
    $.post('/update_data/', {'id': id, 'field': field, 'value': value}, function (response) {
        location.reload();
    })
});
```

What this does is it will update a db table as follows:

```
UPDATE table SET field=value WHERE id=id
```

It would be much simpler to condense the two functions into one though. However, the `value` part is not the same -- one is a checkbox and the other is a select dropdown. Is there a way to get the "value" of these two items in a single function (not just adding an if statement -- but hopefully something more generalizable depending on the input type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to generalize the field update part:

```
function updateField(id, field, value) {
  console.log(id, field, value);
  $.post('/update_data/', {'id': id, 'field': field, 'value': value}, function (response) {
    location.reload();
  });
}

// (3) Change to whether user has an acceptable rate or not
$('.rate-ok').on("change", function(event) {
  updateField($(this).data('id'), 'rate_ok', $(this).is(':checked'));
});

// (4) Change on status
$('.status').on("change", function(event) {
  updateField($(this).data('id'), "status", $(this).find(":selected").val());
});
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. I've used a similar approach -- does mine look too hackish (above), or does that answer seem reasonable?

Comment: Your approach looks reasonable to me since all the necessary details are in data attributes.

Comment: This is the right way. Parameterization for the win

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks for the feedback. Out of curiosity, could you please explain why this approach would be preferable to the one I've added in?

Comment: @David542 mainly because it factors out the relevant parts more precisely and because, with your approach, time any input is changed it will go through all of the checks. Another approach would be an event handler factory.

Answer (score 1):

This way is a bit verbose, but it will handle various types of inputs (including selects) --

```
$('.update-db-on-change').on("change", function(event) {

    // variables are id, field, value
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var field = $(this).data('field');
    var field_type = $(this).attr('type') || $(this).prop('tagName');
    var value;

    // get the value based on the field_type
    if (field_type == 'SELECT') {
        value = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    } else if (field_type == 'checkbox') {
        value = $(this).is(':checked')
    } else if (field_type == 'text') {
        value = $(this).val();
    }

    // update our database
    console.log(id, field, value)
    $.post('/update_data/', {'id': id, 'field': field, 'value': value}, function (response) {
        location.reload();
    })

});
```

Comment: Seems OK but I think it's better to separate the logic into some get value function